# python turtle graphics window won't open

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I have little piece of code from a tutorial which should work fine but I don't get the turtle graphics window to show (I'm on Windows 10 using python 2.7.10). The code looks like this

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.forward(100)

window.exitonclick()
```

However, when I execute it nothing happens, I don't even get an error message. Instead, the shell just says

================================ RESTART ================================

and displays the little Windows circle (indicating it is working on something) but the turtle graphics window does not pop up.

I have tried repairing my python installation and additionally installing the x86 version, but I get the same outcome on the other installation, too.

Does anyone please know how to fix this?

Thank you,
Tomislav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions don't do anything unless you call them. Try:

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.forward(100)

    window.exitonclick()

draw_square()
```